# Appending to file leading to giant mess

Tags: java, io, append, upgrade

In Java, there seems to have been an update to the way the append option works for FileOutputStream between jdk6 and jdk7: The order of lines in the final file seems vastly but structurally different. 
As we are comparing the files constructed in this manner to existing base files for testing purposes, I need to make sure that the order in which notifications are written to these files stays the same when moving to a jdk7 environment. 'Updating' the base files is not an option.

How can one replicate jdk6 behavior for FileOutputStream in append mode in a jdk7 environment?

Comment: Considering how backwards compatible Java is, it's unlikely that there's a significant difference in `FileOutputStream's` handling of the `append` option. It's more likely that your code is broken, but for some reason happened to work correctly on JDK6. Why don't you show the code you have for writing.

Comment: Are you using the same stream from different threads?